# firebase error in flutter windows application

Tags: flutter, windows, firebase

i am trying to build a flutter windows application in android studio. i am using the firebase pulgins in my app. the issue is when i try to build my app it is showing me these kinds of errors so much:

error:

> firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj)' or at 'D:\APPS\eaziprep_admin_app\build\windows\x64\runner\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [D:\APPS\eaziprep_admin_app\build\windows\x64\runner\eaziprep_admin_app.vcxproj]

i have checked everything like updating everything to latest version. also downgraded my visual studio from 2022 to 2019 because this problem rose when i updated my visual studio. before updating my app was building successfully. please if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Visual Studio or Android Studio?

Comment: @GregFenton i am developing application on android studio with flutter.

Comment: Then why the mention of Visual Studio?

Comment: @GregFenton because flutter windows requires the visual studio to build and run application on windows. and its surely a visual studio linker's problem

Comment: @GregFenton can u help me about it?

Comment: Install the visual studio (not vs code). this software installs the Development C++ in your windows machine. just follow the link https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop

Comment: @LakshmananKumar i have visual studio not the vs code and yes my visual studio has all cpp packages installed